# Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate fails with Forbidden error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to use Powershell to upload a certificate PFX file to Key Vault using the command below:

```
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kvName -Name $kvCertName -FilePath $aseCertPFXFile -Password $SecureStringPassword
```

When I run this command, I get the error below:

```
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

I can manually upload this certificate using the portal with no issues and the account I am using to run the PowerShell script is the same one I use when doing it via the portal.

Comment: what permissions do you have on the kv? powershell might require more permissions. try assigning all permissions to the user. also, are you sure its the exact same user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wound up being that there was a residual context from a Service Principal that did not have the necessary permissions to perform the actions. Once I removed that context, it forced a new login where I used my user account and the import worked.